# how can I format a cell in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that have a column containing github issue numbers, how can I make all the fields in that column a url to the issue on github.
lets say https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo/issues/ is where the issues exist, I want to make all those fields link to "https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo/issues/{existing-issue-nb-here}"

#### e.g: in line 54, column B(github issue #) should be a hyperlink to https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo/issues/652

[image]

Comment: Do you want to do it form within the spreadsheet? Then use [HYPERLINK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en), if from a script use it with setFormula()

Comment: ok I was able to do this `=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(https://github.com/myaccount/myrepo/issues/ ,B57), B57)`, now how can I apply this to the column and all new fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never overwrite the first row of the column with the links you can use the HYPERLINK formula inside of an array formula

```
={"github issue #"; 
  ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), 
                  HYPERLINK("https://github.com/myacco‌​unt/myrepo/i‌​ssues/" & B2:B,
                  B2:B), ""))}
```

If you are importing / copy pasting Column B and want to replace it with a link you need to do that with a script that, for every cell does

```
setFormula("=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(https://github.com/myacco‌​unt/myrepo/i‌​ssues/ ,bugId), bugId)")
```

Where bug ID is either read from the row in column B or in the data you retrieved via script.